# ¿Cómo crear una suma consecutiva en Python?

Tags: python

Acabo de iniciarme en Python y estoy programando una función que realice una suma de diversas tiradas de dados:
import random

```
print("Comienzo")
total = 0
for i in range(3):
    dado = random.randrange(1, 7)
    print(f"Tirada {i + 1}: {dado}")
    total += dado
print(f"En total ha obtenido {total} punto(s).")
print("Final")
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el número de tiradas se detenga sólo cuando el total haya llegado a 100 puntos?

Comment: Con un while y un condicional? Sirve mi idea?

Comment: **No vandalices tu pregunta**. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, [formúlala](/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo tú código, para tirar un solo dado en cada jugada solo tienes que cambiar el `for` por un `while`.

```
total = 0
n_tiradas = 0
while total <= 100:
```

Ahora lo que puedes querer es tirar 3 dados en cada jugada, por lo que colocas el `for i in range(3):`  dentro del `while`.

**Opción 1:**

```
print("Comienzo\Tiro 1 dado en cada jugada")
total = 0
n_tiradas = 0
while total <= 100:
    dado = random.randrange(1, 7)
    print(f"Tirada {n_tiradas + 1}: {dado}")
    total += dado
    n_tiradas += 1
print(f'Hice {n_tiradas} tiradas y conseguí {total} puntos')
```

**Opción 2**

```
print("Comienzo\Tiro 3 dados en cada jugada")
total = 0
n_tiradas = 0
while total <= 100:
    valor_tirada = 0
    #tirada = [random.randrange(1, 7) for _ in range(3)]
    tirada = []
    for i in range(3):
        tirada.append(random.randrange(1, 7))

    total_tirada = sum(tirada)
    print(f"Tirada {n_tiradas + 1}: {tirada} => valor tirada = {total_tirada}")
    total += total_tirada
    n_tiradas += 1
print(f'Hice {n_tiradas} tiradas y conseguí {total} puntos')
```

Comment: Gracias Tomy, y si quisiera introducir manualmente el valor de cada tirada después de definir la función y que se fueran sumando, ¿cómo se haría?

Comment: `n=input('Núm. De dados) `   `for i in range(n) :`. Sería añadir algo como eso. Si Si te pongo el código completo no te dejo opción al estudio.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo Tomy!

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> def suma(resultado,valor):
...     resultado += valor
...     print("El resultado de la suma es " + str(resultado))
...     return resultado
...
>>> m = 5
>>> m = suma(m,1)
'El resultado de la suma es 6'
>>> m = suma(m,3)
'El resultado de la suma es 9'
>>> m = suma(m,10)
'El resultado de la suma es 19'
```

Comment: Gracias Yeibi! es un poco complicado empezar, siempre se agradece la ayuda

Comment: Lástima que te cambiaron la pregunta ...

Comment: Luisa, te puedo pasar una guía que he hecho recientemente de Python con básicamente todo lo básico y necesario y algunos temas más avanzados. Lo único que necesitas es GitHub:  https://github.com/yeibi-aholic/Markdown/blob/main/ManualPython.md